# Plugin doesn't work when I use .fn, but does if I leave it off

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am trying to write my first jQuery plugin.  Following the jQuery plugin docs I did this:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.selection = function(array, n) { ... };
}(jQuery));
```

But when I try to run it with some code like this:

```
var array = [5, 2, 1, 5, 9]; 
alert($.selection(array, 2));
```

I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object function (j,s){return new b.fn.init(j,s)} has no method 'selection'`.

However, when I loose the `.fn` like this:

```
(function($) {
  $.selection = function(array, n) { ... };
}(jQuery));
```

Everything works.  Why doesn't the original example work by adding to the `jQuery.fn` object like the jQuery doc suggests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$.fn is the prototype used to jQuery objects created from $("...").

$ is the jQuery factory and namespace.

So

```
$.mymethod = function (){}
```

can only be called through

```
$.mymethod()
```

But

```
$.fn.mymethod = function () { this.remove(); }
```

can be called like this.

```
var divs = $(".mydivs");
divs.mymethod();
```

And in the second example the mymethod will be called using the jQuery selection as object and would remove all matching divs.

Read more here:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 1):

When you use `$.fn.selection` the function is only avalable for jquery objects i.e `$("<SOME_SELECTOR>").selection`

Comment: Does that mean I'm doing the right thing in terms of plugin compatibility to directly add a function to `jQuery`?

Comment: If all you need is a function which doesn't need any specific context like text(), html() etc then your second approach is fine.

Comment: @Rich, Your second solution is like a static method in C#, it does not work on objects of type jQuery but rather use jQuery as a Namespace to put the method in.

Comment: Thanks David and Cybernate, this is what I was looking for.